# GLSL texture1D versus texture2D

Tags: glsl, texture2d, texture1d

I have a very simple question:

It seems that accessing a sampler1D, via texture1D(), is slower than accessing a sampler2D, via texture2D. Is it right ?

Answer (score 1):

As with most performance matters, the performance of texture fetching operations is platform-dependent.